# Crash in Deleting selected items from QTablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have  a QTablewidget with the following settings

```
tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

I am trying to delete the user selected rows and use the following code. However, it results in a crash when all items are selected and deleted. Is the following approach correct ? Thanks.

```
tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> selectedEntries = tableWidget->selectedItems();
foreach(QTableWidgetItem * currentItem, selectedEntries) 

{       
if (currentItem->row()!=-1) 
                      tableWidget->removeRow(currentItem->row());   

}
tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Do you know where it crashes?  Is there a stack trace?

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different flavor of this operation can be found in the [Nokia dev forums](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5069), the evolved form provided by Ruzik looks like..

```
 QSet<int> selectedRows; //we use a set to prevent doubles
 QList<QTableWidgetItem*> itemList = tableWidget->selectedItems();
 QTableWidgetItem * item;
 foreach(item, itemList)
 selectedRows.insert(item->row());
 //get a list, and sort it big to small
 QList<int> rows = selectedRows.toList();
 qSort(rows.begin(), rows.end());
 //now actually do the removing:
 foreach(int row, rows)
  tableWidget->removeRow(row);
```

Comment: Great answer. Used this myself... Although I had to change  qSort(rows.begin(), rows.end()); to  qSort(rows.begin(), rows.end(), qGreater<int>());

Answer (score 0):

It seems this happens because removing the row deletes the items associated with the row, so it could be that in subsequent iterations you iterate over items that were already deleted, which results in accessing invalid memory.

A simple alternative is to use the QModelIndexList to get the selected rows and remove them:

```
QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tableWidget->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
for (QModelIndex index : indexes) {
    ui->tableWidget->removeRow(index.row());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses minimal QT and replaces most of it with C++11 STD / STL code. (if you prefer std to qt like me, but are forced to interop with qt)

```
// make sure it is sorted descending.
std::set<int, std::greater<int>> selectedRows;
auto itemList = tableWidget->selectedItems();
for (auto& item : itemList)
{
    selectedRows.insert(item->row());
}
for (int row : selectedRows)
{
    tableWidget->removeRow(row);
}
```