# QTableWidget crashes on removal of multiple rows

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

I want to remove multiple rows from QTableWidget (three columns), this is my code:

```
void on_del_clicked()
{
    QList<QTableWidgetItem *> items = ui->tableWidget->selectedItems();
    for(int i = 0;i<items.length(); i=i+3)
    {
        int row = items[i]->row();
        if(row>=0)
        {
            ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
            ui->tableWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tableWidget->model()->index(row,0));
        }
    }
}
```

If i choose multiple rows using Ctrl, it works fine, but if I choose multiple entries by dragging mouse, it crashes. It only crashes when selected items are multiple of 3 and rows are selected by dragging mouse. I use Qt 4.8.4 and my OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Comment: Mayby it's because you choose multiple items in the same row and then when you delete row and try to access next element in that row (which actually doesn't exist) you got memory leak.

Comment: @Blood ~> I referenced your comment in my answer :D thank u.

Comment: @adnan kamili - You're welcome :)

Comment: @Blood ~> It was me :|

Comment: Related: [How to remove multiple rows from QTable Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8907511)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crash in Deleting selected items from QTablewidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845069/crash-in-deleting-selected-items-from-qtablewidget)

Comment: Note that the answers on the [question I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845069/crash-in-deleting-selected-items-from-qtablewidget) shows an alternative way to handle this problem, instead of just taking the first one as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190040) suggests, you could sort the indexes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blood is right :

> Mayby it's because you choose multiple items in the same row and then
>   when you delete row and try to access next element in that row.

So use this code instead :

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem*> selected_rows = ui->tableWidget->selectedItems();
while( !selected_rows.isEmpty() )
{
    QTableWidgetItem *itm = selected_rows.at(0);
    ui->tableWidget->removeRow(itm->row());
    selected_rows = ui->tableWidget->selectedItems();
}
```

Comment: I also came up with the same code at last, but I think there is a bug in QtableWidget, check out this link( last reply): http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25341/

Comment: oh yes it must be a bug ! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Just run in debig mode, and see, where your program fails. 
For example, before your cycle you can check if `items` are not empty list, or so on (you may do `qDebug() << list;` before cycle).

One more advice, better to use `items.at(i)` insted of `items[i]`.